# Aplicación android de conteo de cuadros

Tags: java, android, xml, app

Buen día a todos:

Tengo un ejercicio que me gustaría compartir y de ser posible, aportar alguna ayuda:

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual se tiene la pantalla dividida en 100 cuadros (10x10). La función de esta aplicación es muy sencilla = Contar el total de cuadros presionados de una misma fila (lo que daría un total de 10 en caso de se presionada toda una fila.
Lo interesante de esta aplicación es que solamente puede sumar los cuadros presionados de una misma columna, si llega a presionar otro cuadro de una columna, ya sea de arriba o abajo, la aplicación debe restar 1 dependiendo del numero de columnas presionadas.

Por si no queda claro pongo el ejemplo con unas imágenes.

Caso 1:
Presionas los 10 cuadros de una columna = 10 puntos

[image: Caso 1]

Caso 2:
Presionas 5 cuadros de una columna, pero presionas 1 de otra columna consecutiva, por lo que al total de puntos acumulados (5) se le resta un punto (5-1) sin importar si se llegas a presionar posteriormente mas cuadros de esa segunda columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Las columna que se lleguen a presionar de mas,solo restaran 1 punto al total de los cuadros de la primera columna y la primera columna puede iniciar desde cualquier fila, es decir, ya sea que pueda empezar hasta arriba,en medio o al final, el máximo a contar Total sera de 10 y de ahí se irán restando las columnas adicionales presionadas en 1.

Algo que es funcional es que se puede agregar un botón que reinicie la aplicación.

Ahora lo que he hecho yo es lo siguiente:
Primero: para los cuadros, utilice ToggleButton para simular los cuadros presionados.

Segundo: ocupe los atributos android:checked="false" y android:onClick="validarC1F1" en el XML para que cuando estuviera presionado uno de ellos llamara un método que valide el cuadro presionado y empiece a sumar al contador.

Tercero: Para evitar que el cuadro presionado acumule mas de un punto lo bloquee usando el atributo "c1f1.setClickable(false);" en JAVA que después se desbloquea con el botón de reinicio, el cual primero te muestra el resultado final y después reinicia la app.

*También estuve pensando en una comparación para columna con columna empleando un arreglo o vector, sin embargo de momento aun no se como aplicarlos en Android Studio.

Si alguien puede auxiliarme con este caso se los agradecería.

Saludos!!!

De momento estoy haciendo pruebas y esto he hecho en el XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/cuadro" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Confirmar"
        android:onClick="confirmar"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F1"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F1"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F2"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F2"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F3"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F3"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F4"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F4"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F5"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F5"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F6"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F6"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F7"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F7"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F8"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F8"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F9"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F9"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/C1F10"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1F000000"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="validarC1F10"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Y esto es lo que he programado:

package com.example.artcodiac.cortepapel;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int corte = 0;
int altos = 0;
int total = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void validarC1F1 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F1);
    c1f1.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f1.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F2 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F2);
    c1f2.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f2.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F3 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F3);
    c1f3.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f3.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}


public void validarC1F4 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F4);
    c1f4.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f4.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F5 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F5);
    c1f5.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f5.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F6 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f6 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F6);
    c1f6.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f6.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F7 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f7 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F7);
    c1f7.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f7.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}


public void validarC1F8 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f8 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F8);
    c1f8.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f8.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F9 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f9 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F9);
    c1f9.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f9.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void validarC1F10 (View view){
    ToggleButton c1f10 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F10);
    c1f10.setClickable(false);
    if (c1f10.isChecked() == true){
        corte = corte + 1;
        suma(corte,0);
    }
}

public void suma (int contadorC, int contadorA){
    corte = contadorC;
    altos = contadorA;
    total = corte - altos;
}

public void confirmar (View view) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total del corte: "+ total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ToggleButton c1f1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F1);
    c1f1.setChecked(false);
    c1f1.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F2);
    c1f2.setChecked(false);
    c1f2.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F3);
    c1f3.setChecked(false);
    c1f3.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F4);
    c1f4.setChecked(false);
    c1f4.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F5);
    c1f5.setChecked(false);
    c1f5.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f6 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F6);
    c1f6.setChecked(false);
    c1f6.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f7 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F7);
    c1f7.setChecked(false);
    c1f7.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f8 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F8);
    c1f8.setChecked(false);
    c1f8.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f9 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F9);
    c1f9.setChecked(false);
    c1f9.setClickable(true);

    ToggleButton c1f10 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.C1F10);
    c1f10.setChecked(false);
    c1f10.setClickable(true);

    total = 0;
    corte = 0;
    altos = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Debes agregar por favor lo que lleves hecho y los errores claros que tengas

Comment: dale en editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que haga falta ahi

Comment: Mas que error, es que sugerencia o como podría implementar un método en el cual me permita hacer la operación que mencione para el caso 2. Pienso que se puede usar un arreglo pero aun no se como implementarlos